# Producing a sinusoid from a DC input

Tags: circuit-analysis

Here is a simple circuit that I have built which takes as input a DC voltage and gives out a sinusoidal output varying from -V to +V. It has three parts: (1) A LC circuit, (2) a buffer to isolate the LC circuit from the rest of the circuit, and finally (3) the differentiator. I expect to get an output of the form V*cos(wt) where w is the angular frequency of the wave. I'm not sure whether this circuit actually does the job it's supposed to do. Any idea is appreciated.

EDIT: The third part is actually a subtractor and not a differentiator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIh4sx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The circuit has no feedback to drive your LC tank circuit.

Comment: Why don't you simulate it and find out?

Comment: Also, the way the input voltage is connected to your components does not make sense. If it is a low-impendance load (like a bench power supply) it will absorb any oscillation that might occur in your circuit (and as others pointed out, it doesn't even do that). You will have to find another way to specify the output voltage.

Comment: In case you think someone will point out that it will magically oscillate, don't hold your breath.

Comment: I didn't know about oscillators and the role of feedback in that case.

Comment: There's a good web circuit simulator from a guy called falstaad (it's the first google result), it's got lots of example circuits including some voltage controlled oscillators you can try.

Answer (score 5):

I see the L-C tank and the voltage buffer, but there is no differentiator in your circuit.

It's hard to tell how you think this is supposed to work, but it's clearly not going to oscillate.  You will get some short-term ringing as Vin is changed, particularly when it is changed abruptly, but there is nothing to make this circuit oscillate.

A oscillator requires a total loop gain over 1 at some frequency but not at DC.  It should be obvious that this requirement hasn't been met since you don't have any loop at all.  Put another way, there is no feedback path, which is essential to a oscillator.

Comment: The voltage across the cap is an oscillating sinusoid. I used this fact and let it path trough a buffer all the way to subtractor.  The voltage across the cap varies from 0 to 2v. Right? I don't know what it means a feedback path.

Comment: If you don't know what "feedback" means, you have no hope of designing a oscillator except by accident.  Teaching about feedback in general is too much for this site.  Fortunately, there should be lots of reference info out there.  Go study.